# class="d-flex" changes the v-list to flex in all viewports

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

In the Vuetify documentation is written that this class attribute `class="d-flex"` will affect the extra small screens only. However, when I put this class only a v-list it will change the whole component to flex in every viewport.

The Vuetify doc:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/#display

The code:

```
 <v-layout wrap>
<v-flex xs12 sm3 md2 lg2 xl2>
  <v-container>
    <v-sheet rounded="lg">
      <v-list color="transparent" class="d-flex">
        <v-list-item v-for="sideBarItem in sideBar" :key="sideBarItem" link>
          <v-list-item-content @click="changeTab(sideBarItem)">
            <v-list-item-title> {{ sideBarItem }} </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
        <div v-if="tab === 'Feed'">
          <v-divider class="my-2 hidden-sm-and-down"></v-divider>
          <v-list-item
            link
            color="grey lighten-4"
            @click="refreshPosts"
            class="hidden-sm-and-down"
          >
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>
                Refresh
                <v-icon class="mb-1">mdi-refresh</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </div>
      </v-list>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-container>
</v-flex>

<v-flex xs12 sm9 md10 lg10 xl10>
  <v-container>
    <v-sheet min-height="70vh" rounded="lg">
      <PostList v-if="tab === 'Feed'" />
      <AddPost
        v-else-if="tab === 'Add Post'"
        @refreshPosts="refreshPosts"
      />
      <div v-else class="pa-16">
        <v-alert text outlined color="deep-orange" icon="mdi-fire">
          This page is under development! Content will be added soon!
        </v-alert>
      </div>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-container>
</v-flex>
```

Comment: You are correct that `d-flex` equals `d-flex-xs`, but the docs state that this means xs and up. "When setting a specific breakpoint for a display helper class, it will apply to all screen widths from the designation and up."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Documentation says:

> Setting a specific breakpoint for a display helper class, it will
> apply to all screen widths from the designation and up

And follwing:

> `.d-{value}` for xs

So `d-flex` gets applied to all screen widths.

Try following instead:
`class="d-flex d-sm-block"`

This way `display: flex` is set only for `xs` and `display: block` for all other widths.

Comment: Thank you! it worked!

Comment: I'm glad i could help you! :)